# Enhance cpu usage for a specific program

Tags: java, cpu, execution-time

I am working on an NP-hard problem using meta-heuristics, the problem is that in the testing phase the program needs too much time ( over 2 months ). After having a look on the CPU usage i noticed that it doesn't get over 30% of my CPU, even though the rest (70%) is free.
I would like to know if there is a certain way to increase the usage of my CPU to shorten the execution time of my program.
For the record i am using java and an Intel i5-3550 CPU.

Comment: This question is probably too broad and vague to really answer with anything in a way that would really help you.  However, if you can parallelize the algorithm that you're using in some fashion, you could potentially use more of the CPU and get results quicker.  If it's I/O-bound, you could see some gains by speeding up your storage media.  If your specific problem lends itself well to processing with a GPU, you could try porting it to use that.  But without a more specific question, everything is just going to be general ideas.

Comment: At this point, anything that can help me make my program run faster is welcome. My program isn't I/O-bound, and it's a kind of loop that doesn't get along much with parallelism. If only there is a way to tell my CPU " give it all to this program ".

Comment: Unless you parallelize it's probably not going to use more of the CPU. You have a quad core, and so you can have multiple threads being processed at a time, but a single thread in a loop is at most only ever going to max out one of your cores. What I'm guessing is your one program uses most/all of one core (25% of the CPU) and the rest is usually idle. If you're constrained to a single thread and not I/O bound, you're kind of stuck with improving the efficiency of your algorithm/generating more efficient machine code for the processor to run.

Comment: Thank you for your time sir, i feel that this norrows down the issue. Now answer me this " would a more powerful CPU make the program faster ?"

Comment: You're welcome.  It would probably speed things up somewhat, but a lot of the gains from going from an older/less powerful processor to a newer, more powerful one often come in additional cores (which won't help you without a parallel algorithm), with additional gains from more efficient pipelines/better memory/more cache/higher processing speeds/etc.  Check https://www.cpubenchmark.net/singleThread.html for a general idea of how much faster your program could run with a newer processor vs your current one.  You may also consider overclocking your CPU if you have the ability/inclination.

Comment: But I'd still probably try to optimize first.  And you might try implementing the program in a lower level language like C and see if you can get some performance gains that way.  And you should check your OS's resource monitor to see if I'm actually correct that you have one Core mostly always utilized from your process.  If it's not taking up 1/4 of your CPU consistently, you might be able to change something so that it uses the CPU more. You could try assigning that program to a specific core and ensure that nothing else tries to run on that CPU.